# how to make your site be more live with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

hello i am new in stackoverflow,
i trying to build a chat system with HTML , CSS ,PHP & angularjs
but i stack in the middle
my question is why my site doesnt live update with angularjs ?

i trying to get a live select Query from SQL server and when i try to change the value to update the row noting happen in my site only if i am refreshing the site its change the records 
maybe i dont have enough knowlegh about angularjs

**How i should fix this problem ?**

this is my script: index.html

```
<html>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Message }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("demo_index.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

demo_index.php

```
    <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

 //Connection details [SQL]
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "****************";
$password = "***************";
$dbname="**************";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "SELECT * From chat" ;
$outp = "";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows>=0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

     if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"Name":"'  . $row["name"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"id":"'   . $row["id"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"Message":"'. $row["message"]     . '"}'; 
    }




    $outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
    }   


$conn->close();




echo($outp);

?>
```

Comment: app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.names = [];
    $http.get("demo_index.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});

Comment: And use json_encode($arr)/json_decode($str) for JSON encoding/decoding.

Comment: i am using json code and your controller but its doesnt work .

Comment: Hm... did you want just change value in SQL database what should be updated on site without reload? If yes - when: app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$timeout($scope.refreshData, 200);
$scope.refreshData = function(){}
    $http.get("demo_index.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
$scope.refreshData();
});

Comment: But read about sockets, because it is better way. Socket.io will help you )

Comment: i tried your script doesnt work :/ tried to save the file with .php & .html , i am reading about Socket.io for more knowlege , when i edit your script and i put a alert in $scope.refreshData function its show the alert only 1 time i think something wrong in script .

Comment: Change $timeout to $interval ))

Comment: Fixed the problem using other Ajax script thank you very much for help .